# Error in Python code while Web Scraping using beautiful Soup

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

In the python code, it is not giving the expected output. The statement of initializing "divtitle" is not being implemented . Statement of printing "Pass 2 " not in the expected output. Also attaching the expected output.

```
  def scrape():  # after searching the keyword thw page opens, scraping all the headings and content from the search result
global driver
global ctitle
global titles
global links
global titles1


ctitle=""
titles=""
links=""
titles1=""
print ( " Getting Searches")
htmlsrc = driver.page_source
bs = BeautifulSoup(htmlsrc,'html.parser')
print(" BS Implemented ")

    print(" Inside the try function ")
    list1=bs.find('div',attrs={'id':'wgt-list'})
    print(" PAss 1 ")
    divtitle = list1.find_all('dt' , attrs={'class':'dt mb-4 line'})
    print(" Pass 2 ")
    for tlink in divtitle:

      titles=tlink.find('font').gettext()
      print(" Passes the logic, no results returned")


    # for a in bs.find_all('a', href=True):
          # print ("Found the URL:", a['href'])




print (titles)
print (links)
```

The Console Output:

```
 Entered the Search Function 
 Left the Search Function 
 Getting Searches
 BS Implemented 
 Inside the try function 
 PAss 1 
 Pass 2
```

Comment: get rid of the try...except so that you can see the error.

Comment: exactly, and i'm guessing you will get a syntax error because of whatever `****divtitle = list1` this is, remove those ****

Comment: @jdigital I did. nothing happend.

Comment: @OferSadan  Edited. Still no results..

Comment: what do you mean nothing happened? You still get the same output including `Cannot get titles`? What is the error you got?

Comment: @OferSadan  no error are there. only getting the print statement which I hard-coded.

Comment: edit your question with the edited code and current output

Comment: @OferSadan can we move the discussion to skype or something else. Really need help

Comment: nope. we're trying to help, but we need to see the code, that's not hard is it?

Comment: @OferSadan Code and output is the same.

Comment: what do you mean it's the same? you said to @jdigital that you removed the try-except blocks, but it's still there

Comment: @OferSadan Edited

Comment: ok then, now it just doesn't find what you are looking for, and i'm guessing it prints `titles` and `links` that are both `""` empty strings, at the end. Notice it doesn't print "Passes the logic" which means `divtitle` is empty, nothing found there. print `list1` after it's evaluated and see what you're doing wrong there